# Removing Flask session

Tags: python, session, flask, websocket

In my app after logging in, I set:

```
session['venue_id'] = True
```

In my `javascript` I then connect to my `websocket`:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my.ip.address.' + ':' + '80' + namespace);
```

This triggers the following code on my server:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    if session.get('venue_id'):
       session.pop('venue_id', None)
    else:
        request.namespace.disconnect()
```

Following this I make certain calls to my `API` that check:

```
if session.get('venue_id')
```

However, it always goes through fine. I would have thought that these `requests` would not have gone through the `if` statement as `venue_id` had been `popped`?

I read the answer here: [Python + Flask - Removing key from session too fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763887/python-flask-removing-key-from-session-too-fast)

but now I am confused as to what the purpose of `session.pop('venue_id', None)` is?

Any help with clearing this up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a (non-websocket) response to alter the session.  Just popping the value does nothing, as the browser doesn't update it's side and just sends the data again next request.  Right now, the application:

1. Logs in, sets value, returns response
2. Sends request (for websocket), sends value

   1. Whatever response socket sends occurs before `test_connect` event handler, so doesn't pop value
   2. Event handler runs, no way to tell browswer that session has changed
3. Browser sends request for other page, sends value

Probably the simplest solution is to store the session server side, where you can alter it even without sending a response.